# Declare variable with existing table type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to declare variable with existing table type (Table - name: BTC_USDT_OpenOrders)

I want

```
Declare @list BTC_USDT_OpenOrders

INSERT INTO @list
SELECT *
FROM BTC_USDT_OpenOrders
WHERE (Expression)
```

Comment: OK, so what is your question? And its best practice to list the columns you are inserting into, and never use "*" in your select. i.e.  `insert into table1 (col1, col2...) select col1, col2... from table2`

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.   That leaves Dynamic SQL

Comment: @JohnCappelletti unless OP is referring to an existing user defined table type (which is what I assumed - but could be wrong).

Comment: Time to go ask for relation variables on connect again! Oh. I mean... feedback.az... uh... technet I guess?

Comment: @allmhuran I don't know when they'll bring in the next feedback system that might last a few years before they disappear that, too

Comment: LOL @AaronBertrand . I've curtailed providing feedback. I lost some hard work when MS just killed off a User Voice site. Not worth my effort.

Comment: And, Oracle PL/SQL supports OP's ask but SQL Server T-SQL does not.

Comment: @ScottWelker Yeah I'm pretty sure I was Connect user #1 and then one day _poof_ ... they blamed GDPR but the small number of items they brought to UserVoice had all kinds of PII in comments. Now UserVoice got destroyed without a trace too.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but SQL Server does not have `CREATE TABLE (or DECLARE @tableVariable) AS SELECT` functionality (what you are looking for sounds like "[anchored data type](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=type-features)" in DB2-land).

The closest you can come is to have a user-defined table type that is kept in sync with your base table. This can be manual, or you can automate this using a DDL trigger. I would start simple as part of your source control / deploy process.

Another idea is to use a #temp table instead of a table variable ...

```
SELECT * INTO #list FROM BTC_USDT_OpenOrders WHERE <expression>;
```

... which is arguably better in most scenarios anyway (many people have misconceptions that table variables are better for various reasons - for a thorough analysis see [this question over on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16385/1186)).